# Regular expression for 5 digit currency

Tags: regex, currency

I need a regular expression to accept a max value of 99999.99 
I have tried this:
 currencyPattern: /^(\d{0,5})(?:.\d{2})$/

but it accepts 123456 and 1234567 also.

Comment: What's wrong with `\d{0,5}\.\d{2}`?

Comment: [Escape the dot.](https://regex101.com/r/pj5vsy/1)

Comment: thanks. will try this. so decimal needs to be optional. it should accept 123 and 12345 and 12345.34 but not 123.2 and 123456.

Comment: does not accept  whole numbers like 12345. It forces user to enter  a decimal.

Comment: OK, Finally got it working. This is what satisfies all cases. ^\d{0,5}(\.\d{2})?$